# Merging or combining two iOS backups

Tags: ios, backup, restore

In May of 2015 my iPad Mini died because it got wet. I purchased a new iPad Mini 3 and reinstalled the apps I wanted on it ( and mourned the loss of my old Mini).
Now that it's July and my new mini has its own backup I've discovered that I still have the backup to the old Mini (I know, I was pretty dumb that I didn't realize this sooner.)

Is there anyway to restore the old backup to the new iPad without losing the new backup? In other words, can I combine them?

Comment: Short answer: no. Maybe extracting both backups if they are on a computer -made via iTunes, but I wouldn't set my hope too high.

Comment: There is software you can use for data recovery from these backups and have the raw media then combine the two. I don't know any specific one to use but they do exist.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I just did mine only with iPhone.

- Back up new iPad Mini
- then restore backup of old iPad
- after backup complete
- restore backup of new iPad Mini. Viola!

Comment: Typically when you restore an iOS backup it wipes out the existing settings and content on the iOS device. How did you stop this from happening when you restored the second backup?